# Last column does not show information when using csvreader

Tags: tables, csv

I am trying to show a table with two rows and 13 columns, through CSV and csvreader.

As you can see on the contents, there are two X's in the last column of the two rows. However, they are not shown in the column 'M' (see figure). What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable,booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{table7.csv}
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M
Germany,GDP,X,X,,,,,,,X,,X
France,GDP,X,X,,X,,X,,,X,,X
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
  respect all,%
  longtable={|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|},
  separator=comma,
  table head=\caption{List with data.\label{tab:mytable7}}\\
    \toprule\bfseries A &\bfseries B &\bfseries C &\bfseries D &\bfseries E &\bfseries F &\bfseries G &\bfseries H &\bfseries I &\bfseries J &\bfseries K &\bfseries L &\bfseries M \\ \midrule\endfirsthead
    \bottomrule\endfoot,
  late after line=\\,
]{table7.csv}{1=\fieldx,2=\fielda,3=\fieldb,4=\fieldc,5=\fieldd,6=\fielde,7=\fieldf,8=\fieldg,9=\fieldh,10=\fieldi,11=\fieldj,12=\fieldk,12=\fieldl}{\fieldx&\fielda&\fieldb&\fieldc&\fieldd&\fielde&\fieldf&\fieldg&\fieldh&\fieldi&\fieldj&\fieldk&\fieldl}

\end{document}
```

[image: Column M does not show anything. However, the last column of the CSV file does store information]

Comment: You wrote `12=\fieldl` instead of `13=\fieldl`. However your code could be improved. Do you really need a `longtable` for your actual data? Do you know that `booktabs` and vertical rules don't work well together?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you simply wrote `12=\fieldl` instead of `13=\fieldl`.

However, your table could be improved not using vertical rules with `booktabs` or, much better, not using vertical rules at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable,booktabs}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}  

\begin{filecontents*}{table7.csv}
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M
    Germany,GDP,X,X,,,,,,,X,,X
    France,GDP,X,X,,X,,X,,,X,,X
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    You simply wrote \verb|12=\fieldl| instead of \verb|13=\fieldl|.

    But vertical rules with \verb|booktabs| don't go well together. 
    If you want vertical rules, don't use \verb|\toprule|, \verb|\midrule|
    or \verb|\bottomrule| (and increase \verb|\arraystretch|): 

    \csvreader[
    respect all,%
    longtable={|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{0.3cm}|},
    separator=comma,
    table head=\caption{List with data.\label{tab:norules}}\\
    \hline\bfseries A &\bfseries B &\bfseries C &\bfseries D &\bfseries E &\bfseries F &\bfseries G &\bfseries H &\bfseries I &\bfseries J &\bfseries K &\bfseries L &\bfseries M \\ \hline\endfirsthead
    \hline\endfoot,
    late after line=\\,
    ]{table7.csv}{1=\fieldx,2=\fielda,3=\fieldb,4=\fieldc,5=\fieldd,6=\fielde,7=\fieldf,8=\fieldg,9=\fieldh,10=\fieldi,11=\fieldj,12=\fieldk,13=\fieldl}{\fieldx&\fielda&\fieldb&\fieldc&\fieldd&\fielde&\fieldf&\fieldg&\fieldh&\fieldi&\fieldj&\fieldk&\fieldl}

    But it is much better to get rid of the vertical rules:

    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}  
    \csvreader[
    respect all,%
    longtable={*{2}{p{2cm}}*{11}{p{0.3cm}}},
    separator=comma,
    table head=\caption{List with data.\label{tab:norules}}\\
    \toprule\bfseries A &\bfseries B &\bfseries C &\bfseries D &\bfseries E &\bfseries F &\bfseries G &\bfseries H &\bfseries I &\bfseries J &\bfseries K &\bfseries L &\bfseries M \\ \midrule\endfirsthead
    \bottomrule\endfoot,
    late after line=\\,
    ]{table7.csv}{1=\fieldx,2=\fielda,3=\fieldb,4=\fieldc,5=\fieldd,6=\fielde,7=\fieldf,8=\fieldg,9=\fieldh,10=\fieldi,11=\fieldj,12=\fieldk,13=\fieldl}{\fieldx&\fielda&\fieldb&\fieldc&\fieldd&\fielde&\fieldf&\fieldg&\fieldh&\fieldi&\fieldj&\fieldk&\fieldl}

\end{document}
```

[image]